# Are hill climbing variations always optimal and complete?

Tags: search, proofs, hill-climbing, optimality, completeness

Are hill climbing variations (like steepest ascent hill climbing, stochastic hill climbing, random restart hill climbing, local beam search) always optimal and complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are prone to get stuck in local maxima, unless the whole search space is investigated.

A simple algorithm will only ever move upwards; if you imagine you're in a mountain range, this will not get you very far, as you will need to go down before going up higher. You can see that going down a bit will have a net benefit, but the search algorithm will not be able to see that.

Random restart (and similar variations) allow you to do that, up to a point. Imagine you have ten people that you parachute over your mountain range, but they can only go upwards. Now you've got a better chance of finding a higher peak, but there's still no guarantee that any of them will reach the highest one.